# Schedule a job for the first day of each month

Tags: scala, akka, scheduled-tasks

I need to schedule a task for the first day of each month. Up until now, I have been using this:

```
system.scheduler.schedule(0.microseconds, 30.days, schedulerActor, "update")
```

But as you may have guessed it, this ends up sometimes running the task twice a month (march) or none a month (february). Is there a better way to schedule the task for the first day of each month using Akka Scheduler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Built-in Akka scheduler is more a delayer than a scheduler. I would recommend using [akka-quartz-scheduler](https://github.com/enragedginger/akka-quartz-scheduler). This module allows you to actually schedule tasks to run when you want.

The usage is simple. Some config:

```
akka {
  quartz {
    schedules {
      YourScheduleName {
        description = "A cron job that fires off every first of the month at 5AM"
        expression = "0 0 5 1 1/1 ? *"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then in the code:

```
case object Tick
val yourActor = system.actorOf(Props[YourActor])
QuartzSchedulerExtension(system).schedule("YourScheduleName", yourActor, Tick)
```